# How to validate an ARN before applying an AWS policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have a list of ARNs from numerous accounts in a configuration file that I then build into an S3 bucket policy.  But if one of these ARNs is invalid, say `arn:aws:iam::12345679012:user/foo-bar`, then I will get the following exception when trying to apply a policy that includes that ARN:

`` lib/aws/core/client.rb:375:in `return_or_raise': Invalid principal in policy (AWS::S3::Errors::MalformedPolicy) ``

It seems like this could cause problems should any of the ARNs in my file get deleted.  Then, I can't append to the existing policy.  I'd have to find out which ARN is the "poison pill" and delete it.  But the exception message doesn't give that information to me.

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to go about managing a host of cross-account ARNs that I don't control?
2. Is there a way to validate that an ARN exists before applying it to an S3 bucket policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify ruby, so I will show you how I handled this (poorly, I suspect) with the Python Boto3 library.

While trying to update an assumerole policy with a number of ARNs, one or more are invalid.  Here is the boto call which produces an error:

```
try:
  iamClient.update_assume_role_policy(RoleName=curated_role_name, PolicyDocument=json.dumps(assume_role_policy_document))
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
  print (e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

The results from the above code snippet is:

```
Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::42xxxxx:user/idontexist"
```

I then do a simple RE to extract the bad ARN and then attempt to re-apply my update.  If there are still bad ARNs in the list, then I get the next one in the list and remove that.  This recurses until the policy is accepted.

I was searching for exactly the same thing you were - an "ARN Validator".  I didn't find it, so I had to handle it myself.  I thought about checking all the ARNs involved in a separate function, but since it's rare I run into the issue, I didn't want to incur the overhead.

I hope you may find some of this helpful.

Dave O